# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' in python list & dict

Tags: python

```
def datos_relevantes(datos_str, *args):
  """
   Devuelve los datos de determinados encabezados pasados como parámetros
  """
  datos_relev = {}
  for arg in args:
    for encabezado, valores in datos_str.items():
      if arg == encabezado:
        datos_relev[encabezado] = valores

  return [datos_relev]
```

```
def calcular_promedio(datos_str, prov_origen):
    """
    Crear una función 'calcular_promedio' que calcule el promedio de viajeros por viaje en una provincia de origen específica.
    """
    datos_relevante = datos_relevantes(datos_str, "provincia_origen", "viajeros", "viajes")

    if prov_origen in datos_relevantes["provincia_origen"]:
        total_viajeros = sum(datos_relevantes["viajeros"])
        total_viajes = sum(datos_relevantes["viajes"])
        if total_viajes != 0:
            promedio = total_viajeros / total_viajes
            return f"El promedio de viajeros por viaje en {prov_origen} fue: {promedio}"
        else:
            return f"No hay suficientes datos para calcular el promedio en {prov_origen}"
    else:
        return f"No hay suficientes datos para la provincia de origen {prov_origen}"
```

```
datos = openFile()
datos_relevantes(estructura_datos)
provincias_origen = "Chaco"
resultado = calcular_promedio(datos_relevantes(datos, "provincia_origen", "viajeros", "viajes"), provincias_origen)
print(resultado)
```

##### Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

I know that the error is on the list & dict but i dont know how  to corrected.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to call `items` on is a list, not a dict (I'd guess `datos_str`). Why do you expect it to be a dict, or why do you expect a list has an `items` method? You should at least provide a minimal, reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The Python "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'" occurs when we call the items() method on a list instead of a dictionary. To solve the error, call items() on a dict instead.

`datos_str` is a list, so it does not have an `items`attribute.

`datos_str.items()` is causing the error.